# String search for multiple values

Tags: java, string

I have a problem statement, wherein I need to search a huge text with list of values. And the result of the search should be the value that is found, not the Boolean value true or false.

Ex:

```
String str = "this a sample string for java search";  
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("java", "net");
```

So if I search the `String str` with `values`, the result should of this search should be "java", since `str` contains `"java"`. Is there any library to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want all values found as returned list?

You can use the `java.util.Set.retainAll(Collection<?>)` function.

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "this is a sample string for java search";

        Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("java", "net", "a"));
        Set<String> split = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")));
        values.retainAll(split);

        System.out.println("Values found in text: "+values);

    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Values found in text: [a, java]

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first matching value you can use the `Stream` api :

```
String value = values.stream()
                     .filter(str::contains)
                     .findFirst()
                     .orElse(null);
```

And if you want all:

```
values.removeIf(s -> !str.contains(s));
```

Which leaves `values` to contain only the elements that are contained inside `str`

Or if you don't want to modify `values`:

```
List<String> newValues = values.stream()
                               .filter(str::contains)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: wouldn't Collectors.toSet() be better?

Comment: @StephanHogenboom well `values` is already a `List` (which i assume is distinct) so the result can not be more distinct. But I agree a `Set` would probably be better